# Why LocalDate.plusDays not working here?

Tags: java, localdate

I'm trying to split a date range into individual dates in the following way:

```
private static void splitDates(LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo) {
    while (dateFrom.isBefore(dateTo) || dateFrom.isEqual(dateTo)) {
        System.out.println(dateFrom);
        dateFrom.plusDays(1L);
    }
}
```

And I don't know why `dateFrom.plusDays(1L)` is not working as the date remains still the same so the loop becomes infinite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[plusDays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusDays-long-) doesn't alter the original `LocalDate`, you have to assign the result :

```
dateFrom = dateFrom.plusDays(1L);
```

Comment: Wonderful, and super-fast answer!

Answer (score 5):

Because method plusDays doesn't change variable dateFrom. You should do like this:

```
dateFrom = dateFrom.plusDays(1L);
```

Comment: Obsolete, @Berger was faster than me :)