# Adding days to ZonedDateTime does not change the time

Tags: java, kotlin, zoneddatetime

I am trying to get an instance of `ZonedDateTime` then add 1 day to it then I want to know what the time is in mills at UTC but when I use `plusDays` the time stays the same and I am not sure why

here is what I am doing

```
val zdt: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now()

println("${zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()}")

zdt.plusDays(1)

println("${zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()}")

zdt.withHour(0)
zdt.withMinute(0)
zdt.withSecond(0)

println("${zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()}")
```

all print statements print out the same value, what am I missing here?

Here is a link to the code sample

https://pl.kotl.in/QmlXRd-HM

Comment: Related: [Why LocalDate.plusDays not working here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933397/why-localdate-plusdays-not-working-here)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those methods don't modify the `ZonedDateTime` instance. They return new ones. The *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

To fix your code, update the variable:

```
var zdt: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
println("${zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()}")
zdt = zdt.plusDays(1)
println("${zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()}")
zdt = zdt.withHour(0).withMinute(0).withSecond(0)
println("${zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli()}")
```

Comment: ahhh I did not know that, makes sense thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why `ZonedDateTime.now()` when you are obviously just interested in epoch millis?

You could use only `Instant`s instead:

```
fun main() {
    var now = Instant.now()
    var nowPlusOneDay = now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    println("now:           ${now.toEpochMilli()}")
    println("one day later: ${nowPlusOneDay.toEpochMilli()}")
}
```

Output (some seconds ago):

```
now:           1695392676969
one day later: 1695479076969
```

Comment: Because a day is not always 24 hours, which `Instant` assumes it is.

Comment: May be a valid reason…